# I want to store all json data in flowfile attribute in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Here is a scenario where I've data in flowfile in json format which is splited using split json and I want to store all the data of single row in the flowfile attribute. I'm trying to use updateattribute processor where through sources I came to know that we can use '${file:toBase64()}' expression to a variable to store all data in base 64 format to the variable and that variable will be added to flowfile attribute having all data.

Here after using '${file:toBase64()}' I'm getting error that it is not a valid expression. Please help me that why it is showing error and if do not have any idea regarding this then provide me a solution where I can store all the key values pairs of json data somewhere so that I can retrieve it later after some processor execution is done. *The data will vary so evaluatejsonpath or updateattribute will not work.

[image: Error picture]

Comment: The expression `${file:toBase64()}` you mentioned is not a valid expression because the `file` variable is not applicable in the context of NiFi's Expression Language. You might have to do a workaround by using `EvaluateJsonPath` and then use the `AttributesToJson`.  Also, keep in mind that its not ideal to store lots of Key Value pairs in Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid parsing content to attributes as that is a NiFi Best Practices Anti-Pattern.   If you want to build a dataflow to process key/value pairs and store them later you should take a look at Distributed Map Cache and internal nifi data store.  You can also use an external data store like hbase, cassandra, or redis amongst others.   You will find a Put and Fetch Processor, a Controller Services Client and Server.  Docs Below.

References:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.DistributedMapCacheClientService/index.html

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.server.map.DistributedMapCacheServer/index.html

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDistributedMapCache/index.html

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchDistributedMapCache/index.html